# Rendering error when using EditText widget inside LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am working on `CrimeIntent` app in *Android Programming:
The Big Nerd Ranch Guide*. I got a rendering problem when i put an `EditText` widget in a `LinearLayout` file for a fragment (`fragment_crime.xml`).Here is the code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText android:id="@+id/crime_title"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:hint="@string/crime_title_hint"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I do not want to change the theme.

Comment: What sort of rendering problem?

Comment: there is no error in xml... possible it is the plugins and library loading issue in android studio... try to restart it or check the missing libraries and targets.. or check the `@string/crime_title_hint` if it exists in `Strings.xml` resources.

Comment: Thanks 
You are right @sourabh i restarted android studio and it works well

Comment: ok... i am posting it as answer,,, kindly accept it.. cuz it may usefull to someone in future,..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error in your layout xml... possible it is the plugins and library loading issue in android studio... try to restart it or check the missing libraries and targets.. or check the @string/crime_title_hint if it exists in Strings.xml resources.